# Visualforce email template with icons

Tags: visualforce, email-template

I am trying to use the icon is salesforce in my visualforce template.

https://test.cs17.my.salesforce.com/profilephoto/005/T

But in the email it is breaking and I see in the img src is appended with some other urls..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it this way, I suggest the following approach:

1. Download and upload the image under the Documents tab. Make sure the image is saved as Externally Available.
2. In the email template, select Insert image and insert the image from the document folder.

This should work and you will be able to see the image in the final email.